# node js, make https post request to google api

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, https, google-api

I am trying to integrate google account login into the node.js application i am building and i have a little problem sending a https post request to google api gate.

At first i was following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) and it worked alright, but they stated in it that for backend processing of google account id, one should do this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth). I started to having problems at that point. I didnt want to use any extra libraries, just native node.js functionality to get my head around how its done.

In order to validate account on backend, one needs to securely post o token id to a given url.

This is the client side code that is working:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send('id_token=' + token_id);
```

Now when i tried to do it with nodejs on server side it didnt work. I tried with the code i found on nodejs docs:

```
var http = require('http');
var post_data = 'id_token=' + token_id;

var post_options = {
    host: 'googleapis.com',
    port: '80',
    path: '/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
};

var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
    });
});

post_req.write(post_data);
post_req.end();
```

The response from google was 404 error `The requested URL /oauth2/v3/tokeninfo was not found on this server. That's all we know.` Which means that i did something wrong. So my questions are:

1. how can i improve/fix my code so it executes proper post https request?
2. how do i know that it will be a https request (not http)?

Thank You for any help ;)

Comment: For one thing, you're using http instead of https on the node side. Did you try changing that?

Comment: well, i didnt find how to change that, or even how to check that. but i think its not the only problem here, i think that also something is wrong with general request structure, as the error says page doest exists. dont really know if i am doing it right, thats why i included working client version example to have an idea how it should look like.

Comment: To change it all you need to do is basically replace `http` with `https` everywhere and either leave off `port` or change it to `443`.

Comment: there are no http references in entire code (except module name) and port 443 is returning socket error.

Comment: The module name has to be `https` to make https request (`require('https')`). That's the most important change (aside from the `port` change). Changing the variable name and references just makes things clearer.

Comment: ok i changed module to `https` and port to `443` and request was made but google still responded with page 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the difference in protocol (http vs https), you're also missing the `www` subdomain in the hostname (like what is being used in your client-side example). Changing it from `host: 'googleapis.com'` to `host: 'www.googleapis.com'` should work.

Comment: this indeed solved the problem. So calling `https` module, changing port `80 -> 443` and adding `www` to host is the final answer. Thank You, that is a lot of good work.